# Word list intersection that extracts strings, containing a combination of two words

Tags: list, cpu-word, intersection

So, the source data is a sorted dictionary word list, and a list of random unsorted strings.

The task is to extract from the list with random strings only the ones that are a combination of two words from the dictionary list.

Dictionary list:

```
ace
dice
nice
task
test
try
```

Random list:

```
test123task
testtask
bbtesttask
bbtest1task
nicetry
nicetesttry
nice1task
1nicetry
```

Result:

```
testtask
nicetry
```

Have you come across a script that does this and can handle large lists? I'm not quite sure that I would be able to program this myself. I'm thinking of an algorithm that processes the list once and extracts the list of words that start with a keyword. It should add some sort of an index number for the letter where the first string ends.

Then, the list is processed once again, starting from index+1, until the end.

Any directions about a ready solution, or where to start, are welcome. I have some limited experience with PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Well, it's because I haven't paid enough attention to detail... I added it to the dictionary. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start:

Take a word from the Random List:

```
test123task
```

Search (with a binary search) `t` in the dictionary list. If a word starts by `t`, search `te`, if found, search `tes`, etc. `test1` is not found, so you stay at `test` which is an actual word in the dictionary and search the word `1`, nothing start by `1` so backtrack. But `tes`, `te` and `t` are not words. `test123task` is not correct.

Another example:

```
testtask
```

Search `t`, `te`, `tes`, `test`, `testt`. Backtrack at `test`. `test` is a correct word, continue from here. Search `t`, `ta`, `tas`, `task`. `task` is a correct word. Return success.

You input data is not very interesting because in some cases you might need to stop at a shorter word. Let's add `tes` in the dictionary. And test this word:

```
`testask`
```

Search `t`, `te`, `tes`, `test`, `testa`. Backtrack at `test`. `test` is a correct word, continue from here. Search `a`, `as`. Backtrack at `a`. `a` is not a correct word. Backtrack to `tes`. `tes` is a correct word, continue from here. Search `t`, `ta`, `tas`, `task`. `task` is in the dictionary, return success.

From this three examples, you should be able to write the recursive algorithm that use backtracking in order to test all the possibilities.